# how to create Xamarin.Forms applications with .Net Standard 2.0 libs and SQLite?

Tags: c#, android, .net, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have visual studio 2017 I am trying to create an application in xamarin forms, which stores data in a sqlite database. all the examples I find are using sqlite.net-pcl, which is no longer compatible with the new netStandard 2.0 libraries, anyone has an example, or know that sqlite libraries I can download from nuget to create a compatible application with NetStandard 2.0 thank you very much .

Comment: What's you mean "no longer compatible with the new netStandard 2.0 libraries"? You can't install this library to your project? Is there any error stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been sucessfully using [sqlite-net-standard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-standard/) package in a Xamarin.Forms project targeting .NET Standard 2.0 framework.